# how the function of recursion works

Tags: javascript, mozilla

how the function of `recursion` works, or how to understand this function??:

```js
function foo(i) {    
 if (i < 0)      
  return;    
  console.log('inicio:' + i);    
  foo(i - 1);    
  console.log('fin:' + i); 
}  
foo(3);
```

which throws as a result:
inicio:3
inicio:2
inicio:1
inicio:0
fin:0
fin:1
fin:2
fin:3

Isn't it supposed to be:

inicio:3
fin:3
inicio:2
fin:2
inicio:1
fin:1
inicio:0
fin:0

This is the reference: "https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones"

Comment: `It is not supposed to be:` correct, it is not supposed to be that, and it isn't - so, recursion is working correctly - if you really want the second output, then `setTimeout(() => foo(i - 1), 0);` instead of `foo(i - 1)` will do that

Comment: @JaromandaX: Do you mind to elaborate more on how this function works on how it growing `i` back up to 3? I have similar question as we have base condition `if (i < 0) return; ` and when `i` dropped to -1 it should be exited

Comment: @JaromandaX: From the documentation, I don't understand how stack coming into picture too `It is possible to convert any recursive algorithm to a non-recursive one, but often the logic is much more complex and doing so requires the use of a stack. In fact, recursion itself uses a stack: the function stack.`

Comment: (synchronous) javascript executes in the sequence you write it in ... you don't need to concern yourself about stacks to understand that code - except if you pass a HUGE number to `foo()` of course - then you'll see a stack overflow first hand

Comment: yes friend, thanks for answering, if I understand what you say, but what interests me to know is why it throws as resulato: inicio:3
inicio:2
inicio:1
inicio:0
fin:0
fin:1
fin:2
fin:3, what are the steps that the function does, or rather how the code is interpreted

Comment: Exactly, Isaac, is also another doubt that I have assumed that when the variable "i" is less than "0" (i <0), it should end the function by the statement "return" and not write the statement: "document. writeln ('end:' + i); "

Comment: do you ever see `end: -1`? in that case the `document. writeln ('end:' + i);` is never executed when `i < 0`, so not sure why you are confused at something that isn't even there

Comment: Very sad to see people learning recursion from examples like this

Comment: but when the function foo () reads a return statement, that function should end, therefore it should not write the statement "document.writeln ('end:' + i);", however this is written in the same way, that's what I do not understand !!, it happens later if the function was found with a "return". if nothing or nobody "invokes or calls"

Comment: It is very sad to see an fool like you  @user633183, who has more knowledge giving an answer like that, to someone who is starting with a programming language

Answer (score 1):

think of your code as doing this

```
foo(3), so i is 3
    document.writeln('inicio: 3');    
    call foo(3 - 1); => foo(i = 2), so i is 2
        document.writeln('inicio: 2');    
        call foo(2 - 1); => foo(i = 1), so i is 1
            document.writeln('inicio: 1');    
            call foo(1 - 1); => foo(i = 0), so i is 0
                document.writeln('inicio: 0');   
                call foo(0 - 1); => foo(i = -1), so i is -1
                    return before any output, because -1 < 0
                document.writeln('fin: 0'); 
            document.writeln('fin: 1'); 
        document.writeln('fin: 2'); 
    document.writeln('fin: 3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Following iteration of your function

Here we call our function foo(3) 
So the value of i = 3
we are taking stack to understand the whole function while function call we will add value in stack

iteration 1 :
**Stack : [3]**

```
        if (3 < 0)   -> result false 
        output -> inicio: 3
        Now call again -> foo ( 2)
```

iteration 1.2 :
**stack : [3,2]**

```
        if (2 < 0)   -> result false 
        output -> inicio: 2
        Now call again -> foo ( 1)
```

iteration 1.3 :
**stack : [3,2,1]**

```
        if (1 < 0)   -> result false 
        output -> inicio: 1
        Now call again -> foo ( 0)
```

iteration 1.2 :
**stack : [3,2,1,0]**

```
        if (0 < 0)   -> result true
```

Now it's again continue next statement which is " console.log('fin:' + i); " using stack value one by one

iteration 1 :
**stack : [3,2,1,0]**

```
        pop stack value which is '0'
        output -> fin: 0
```

iteration 2 :
**stack : [3,2,1]**

```
        pop stack value which is '1'
        output -> fin: 1
```

iteration 3 :
**stack : [3, 2]**

```
        pop stack value which is '2'
        output -> fin: 2
```

iteration 4 :
**stack : [3]**

```
        pop stack value which is '3'
        output -> fin: 3
```

Now stack is empty so return from function execution